# How to reference Firestore sub-collection with generated ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking to reference the items in a subcollection I have in FireStore.

I used `addDoc` which generates a unique id for each document created. The problem is that I cannot access the collections of a document without knowing the name of the document. Each document has a unique document, so I am unsure how to reference this in my table.

```
function HomeQuestion8(){
const[rows, setRows] = useState([]);
const empCollectionRef = collection(db, 'users', "ID", "personalDetails" );



const [docs] = useCollectionData(empCollectionRef)
console.log(docs)
useEffect(()=> {
    getUsers()
}, [])

const getUsers = async() => {
    const data = await getDocs(empCollectionRef);
    // console.log(ydocs)
    setRows(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})))
}
```

Here is the images of my Firestore Database. The data is structured as follows:

collection: "users" -> doc(generatedID)->collection:"personalDetails"

[image]

[image]

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Going forward, please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: In general, nosql data modeling suggests that you know what queries you want ahead of time, then structure your data to satisfy those queries.  If you model first without thinking about your queries, this sort of thing is likely to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the personal details for one specific user, you will need to know the document ID for that user's (parent) document - so their document in the `Users` collection.

If you don't know their document ID, but do know their email address, you can find the document ID for that email address by [using a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).

If you know nothing about the user, all you can do is access the personal details for all users. To do this, you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection_group), which accesses documents from all collections with a specific name (i.e. `personalDetails`).